# Как сделать нормальную рамку в приложении? - Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Qt::FramelessWindowHint убирает стандартную рамку из Windows.
Но вместе с этим пропадает возможность изменять размер окна.
Как это исправить?

Comment: Вручную делать все

Comment: Это я понимаю, но как?!

Comment: Абсолютно все действия, связанные с рамкой реализовать нужно. А как - это вам решать.